# Find price feed contracts Addresses of chainlink within smart contracts

Tags: polygon, smartcontracts, chainlink

I am developing a contract in which I have to check whether the incoming token is paired with USD to get the price feed of Chainlink from the smart contract. Only such tokens are going to be added to my smart contract. Does Chainlink have any functions to get the verified or registered list of pairs from a smart contract?

I have gone through https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/feed-registry, which supports only a few tokens on the Ethereum Mainnet. I am developing my application on the Polygon mainnet.

1. I have to only accept tokens that are verified feed pairs with USD on the Polygon Mainnet.
2. Query Chainlink data feeds of such pairs from asset addresses directly from the smart contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Feed Registry](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/feed-registry) is only avaiable on [Ethereum Mainnet](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/feed-registry#contract-addresses)

I suggest you create your own table to manage it on Polygon.